# How to present a Selenium test written in spec or PHPUnit on Hudson

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, hudson, rspec, phpunit

I am setting up Selenium tests on Hudson and looking for an easy way to present nice results such as Project summary and build summary on Hudson.
Currently I have written Selenium test cases in Rspec and PHPUnit's extension for Selenium (I prefer working on Rspec over PHP).

What is the best way to present detailed report for Selenium tests on Hudson CI Server? 
I prefer to use Rspec over PHPUnit. It would be very nice if I can use rspec and still integrate well with Hudson CI Server.

I would very much appreciate for detailed comments.
thank you so much for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the results as HTML files, you can use the HTML Publisher plugin.

Have a look at a similar question https://serverfault.com/questions/184805/how-to-view-test-results-in-hudson/185027#185027 This guy seams to have integrated the selenium tests into junit and therefore the results can be published using the xunit tests.

There are two selenium plugins, one should work for you.

This I have no idea what rspec is I entered rspec and Hudson into google. The second link was this one http://reprocessed.org/blog/easy_rails_ci_with_hudson It should contain everything you need.

Comment: Hey Peter, thank you so much for the comment! I finally got it working with PHPUnit. this post helped me work it out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518083/how-might-i-integrate-phpunit-with-hudson-ci I used Phing to build a test, make xml to JUnit convertible, and read it on Hudson. thanks for your comment!