# PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server when I run with Hudson

Tags: php, selenium, continuous-integration, hudson, phpunit

I have set up Hudson CI Server and running PHPUnit test with Selenium (big thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518083/how-might-i-integrate-phpunit-with-hudson-ci)!). 
Now I am running Hudson server and Selenium server on my localhost.
I set up Hudson as port 8080 (default) and Selenium -port 1234 as it conflicts otherwise.

However, every time I run Selenium test, I get a following error:

> PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server.
>
> /Users/***/.hudson/jobs/Selenium/workspace/sampleTest.php:28
>   /usr/lib/php/phing.php:37

where line 28 is an assertion:
$this->assertElementContainsText($html, "this is sample test");

and here is my Selenium setup function:

> function setUp()   {
>   $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
>   $this->setHost("localhost");
>   $this->setPort(1234);
>   $this->setBrowserUrl("example.com");
>   $this->setTimeout(100000);   }

how can I avoid this error message? 
your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing ajax? If so, you need to remove your `waitForPageToload()` functions with a `waitForElement()`.  I used selenium IDE to generate the code for me.