# Hudson CI and PHPUnit: None of the test reports contained any result

Tags: xml, junit, hudson, phpunit

Im trying to integrate my PHPUnit tests into Hudson using the xUnit plugin. After a successfull build with Ant in hudson, the console output shows:

Recording test results
None of the test reports contained any result

My junit.xml test output using phpunit --log-junit looks as follows:

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="Unit Tests" tests="1" assertions="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.005112">
  <testsuite name="DbTest" file="src/tests/unit/DbTest.php" tests="1" assertions="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.005112">
    <testcase name="testConnection" class="DbTest" file="src/tests/unit/DbTest.php" line="4" assertions="1" time="0.005112"/>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
I just created a test junit.xml containing:

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="DbTest" file="src/tests/unit/DbTest.php" tests="1" assertions="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.005112">
    <testcase name="testConnection" class="DbTest" file="src/tests/unit/DbTest.php" line="4" assertions="1" time="0.005112"/>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

With this in place, a build was successful. The problem seems to be the nested -tags. Any idea how to prevent PHPUnit to create these nested tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution at [How might I integrate phpunit with Hudson CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518083/how-might-i-integrate-phpunit-with-hudson-ci) using th xslt workaround.

If anyone has the same problem: Create a new .xsl file anywhere below your project root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="testsuites">
        <xsl:for-each select="//testsuite[@file]">
                 <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then add to your build.xml (don't forget to include in the build target):

```
<target name="phpunit_to_xunit">
  <xslt in="build/logs/phpunit.xml" out="build/logs/junit.xml" style="phpunit_to_xunit.xsl"/>
</target>
```

Anyway, this is somehow cumbersome. Therefore I already created a improvement suggestion to the xUnit project.